# Hyperlink in a gridview with datasource

Tags: asp.net

I am having trouble with binding a gridview to a DataTable and adding a hyperlink
The gridview contains 5 columns. 
All 5 come from a Datable

But the 5th column should be a hyperlink.

Any clues on how to do this

Thanks
SC

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
      AllowPaging="true" pagesize ="25"
     style="margin-right: 7px" HeaderText="">

     </asp:GridView>

GridView4.DataSource = PurchaseDetailsdt;
        GridView4.DataBind(); This Datatable contains 5columns. col1, col2, col3, col5, col5(assume). I want to convert this col5 to a hyperlink.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you would use a HyperlinkField:

http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2006/09/10/How-To_3A00_-Use-a-HyperLink-control-inside-a-GridView.aspx